# Pivoting Multiple Attributres and grouping them as a 'single' attribute (many to one)

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

So I Have a table called Value that's associated with different 'Fields'. Note that some of these fields have similar 'names' but they are named differently. Ultimately I want these 'similar names' to be pivoted/grouped as the same field name in the result set

```
  VALUE_ID      VALUE_TX       FIELD_NAME     Version_ID
      1          Yes             Adult           1
      2          18              Age             1
      3          Black           Eye Color       1 
      4          Yes             Is_Adult        2
      5          25              Years_old       2
      6          Brown           Color_of_Eyes   2
```

I have a table called Submitted that looks like the following:

```
  Version_ID   Version_Name
     1         TEST_RUN
     2         REAL_RUN
```

I need a result set that Looks like this:

```
  Submitted_Name    Adult?     Age     Eye_Color
     TEST_RUN       Yes        18      Black
     REAL_RUN       Yes        25      Brown
```

I've tried the following:

```
  SELECT * FROM (
                  select value_Tx, field_name, version_id
                    from VALUE
                )
          PIVOT (max (value_tx) for field_name in (('Adult', 'Is_Adult')   as 'Adult?', ('Age', 'Years_old') as 'Age', ('Eye Color', 'Color_of_Eyes') as 'Eye_Color')
           );
```

What am I doing wrong? Please let me know if I need to add any additional details / data.

Thanks in advance!

The error message that I am getting is the following:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Comment: What is wrong with your query?  If you are getting a syntax error, include it in the question.  If you are getting incorrect results, then share those.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff I am getting a syntax error, I was googling how to possibly do this but couldn't find any documentation on how to achieve the result set that I wanted to grab. I added the error message to the original question but I am not sure if that'll really help much, haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the field names in the subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (select value_Tx,
             (case when field_name in ('Adult', 'Is_Adult') then 'Adult?'
                        field_name in ('Age', 'Years_old') then 'Age'
                        field_name in ('Eye Color', 'Color_of_Eyes') then 'Eye_Color'                        
                   else field_name
              end) as field_name, version_id
      from VALUE
     )
PIVOT (max(value_tx) for field_name in ('Adult?', 'Age', 'Eye_Color'));
```

Comment: Wouldn't the last PIVOT clause be: (max(value_tx) for field_name in ('Is_Adult', 'Adult', 'Age', 'Years_old', 'Eye_color', 'Color_of_eyes')); ?

Comment: @JohnWick . . . No.  The subquery renames the field names.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I couldn't mark yours as the best answer (I can only select one :() is there anything I can do to repay you?

Comment: @JohnWick . . . This certainly seems simpler than the other answer.

Comment: By the way should the last in statement read ('Adult', 'Age', 'Eye_Color')?

Answer (score 1):

You can use double quotes for column aliasing within the pivot clause's part, and I think `decode` function suits well for this question. You can consider using the following query :

```
with value( value_id, value_tx, field_name, version_id ) as
(
 select 1 ,'Yes'  ,'Adult'        ,1 from dual union all
 select 2 ,'18'   ,'Age'          ,1 from dual union all
 select 3 ,'Black','Eye_Color'    ,1 from dual union all
 select 4 ,'Yes'  ,'Is_Adult'     ,2 from dual union all
 select 5 ,'25'   ,'Years_old'    ,2 from dual union all
 select 6 ,'Brown','Color_of_Eyes',2 from dual    
), Submitted( version_id, version_name ) as
(
 select 1 ,'TEST_RUN' from dual union all
 select 2 ,'REAL_RUN' from dual    
)    
  select * from
  (
    select s.version_name as "Submitted_Name", v.value_Tx, 
           decode(v.field_name,'Adult','Is_Adult','Age','Years_old','Eye_Color',
                               'Color_of_Eyes',v.field_name) field_name
      from value v
      join Submitted s 
        on s.version_id = v.version_id
     group by decode(v.field_name,'Adult','Is_Adult','Age','Years_old','Eye_Color',
                                  'Color_of_Eyes',v.field_name),
              v.value_Tx, s.Version_Name
  ) 
  pivot(
         max(value_tx) for field_name in ( 'Is_Adult' as "Adult?", 'Years_old' as "Age", 
                                           'Color_of_Eyes' as "Eye_Color" )
       );

Submitted_Name  Adult?  Age Eye_Color
REAL_RUN        Yes     25  Brown
TEST_RUN        Yes     18  Black
```

I think, better to solve as much as shorter way, as an example, using modular arithmetic would even be better as below :

```
select *
  from
  (
    select s.version_name as "Submitted_Name", v.value_Tx, mod(v.value_id,3) as value_id
      from value v
      join Submitted s 
        on s.version_id = v.version_id
     group by v.value_Tx, s.version_name, mod(v.value_id,3)
  ) 
  pivot(
         max(value_tx) for value_id in ( 1 as "Adult?", 2 as "Age", 0 as "Eye_Color" )
       )
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/DLRFB47218)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, however I want Is_Adut and Adult both pivoted as 'Adult?', 'Years_old and Age' pivoted as 'Age' and 'Color of Eyes and Eye_color' pivoted as 'Eye_Color'. Will this do this?

Comment: @JohnWick You're welcome John. But Answer for your question is No, we can not list in such a manner, ambiguity occurs in that case and has no sense, those are already grouped literals.

Comment: For some reason , I'm trying to apply it to a bigger query but it's not working. I must be doing something wrong... :(

Comment: Also, let's say that there are >3 field_names that need to be categorized into 'Adult?'... would decode still work in this scenario?

Comment: @JohnWick of course, you can list how much you want. By the way examine the last method which numeric, flexible and better I think.

Comment: Thank you. So would my new decode statement (in that case) look like this?           decode(v.field_name,'Adult','Is_Adult', 'Adult_Y', 'Age','Years_old', 'Years', 'Eye_Color', 'Color_of_Eyes', 'Color_Eye', v.field_name)

Comment: @JohnWick No, I didn't mean this (with values inserted middle), I meant pairs for each property(Here,there are triples) [decode function](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php)

Comment: thanks so much, i marked your answer as 'best answer'. so you're saying the 2nd example has triples correct?

Comment: So... does the 2nd example use triples? Would that allow me to use triples? haha. Maybe this is out of scope of the current question and I should ask a second one? (apologies in advance)

Comment: @JohnWick not important :)

Comment: huh? But I need to know how i can use triples... What if I want to categorize 'Adult', 'Is_Adult' and 'Adult_y' all under 'Adult?'; how would I do that?

Comment: @JohnWick In this case, use `decode(v.field_name,'Adult','Is_Adult','Adult','Adult_y',v.field_name)` for the select and group by lists. i.e. you need to repeat one of the literals as the header.

Comment: So would my code change to: decode(v.field_name,'Adult?','Is_Adult','Adult','Adult_y', 'Age',  'Years_old', 'Years', 'Eye_Color', 'Eye_Color', 'Color_of_Eyes', 'Color_Eye', v.field_name) if I want to include the other 2 dimensions / attributes? (sorry for the gazillion questions) :(

Comment: @JohnWick No, consider `decode(v.field_name,'Adult','Is_Adult','Adult','Adult_y',
                               'Age','Years_old', 'Age', 'Years',
                               'Eye_Color', 'Color_of_Eyes', 'Eye_Color', 'Color_Eye',
                  v.field_name)` as extended.